# Does Elemental Weapon get applied to the Bonus Action attack of Polearm Master?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

As mentioned in this question, [Shillelagh and Polearm Master Interaction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/shillelagh-and-polearm-master-interaction), Shillelagh appears to allow Wisdom-based fighting on the Bonus Action attack, but because Polearm Master specifies a d4 damage die, and because Polearm Master's damage die is the more specific case, it is not overwritten by Shillelagh's d8 damage die.

Therefore, a Shillelagh Polearm Master Bonus Action Attack will be a Wisdom-based attack with 1d4 damage.

However, in the case of Elemental Weapon, which provides a +1 to attack rolls and bonus +1d4 damage of a specific element, does that get applied to your Polearm Master Bonus Action attack?

I'm inclined to say yes, but [Jeremy Crawford did not say much on the previous Shillelagh question](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/09/02/shillelagh-on-quarterstaff/) and I'd be interested to know if there's more information on the topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, it does.

The [Polearm Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/polearm-master) feat (PHB, p. 168) states:

> [...] you can use a bonus action to make a **melee attack** with the opposite end of the weapon. The weapon’s damage die for this attack is a d4, and the attack deals bludgeoning damage.

The reason why *shillelagh* and Polearm Master interfere is because [*shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) also states

> [...] the weapon’s damage die becomes a d8.

However, [*elemental weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-weapon) (PHB, p. 237) simply states that you get a bonus to attack rolls (which PM grants) and deal an extra 1d4 damage when it hits:

> For the duration, the weapon has a +1 bonus to **attack rolls** and deals an extra 1d4 damage of the chosen type **when it hits**.

Regardless of which end of the weapon hits, the weapon altogether did hit, hence you get both the +1 and the +1d4 bonus damage.